# Why is exported variable blank after script is over?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a simple command in a Linux shell script (say foo.sh). In it I do this:

```
export INSTALL_DIR=/mnt/share/TEST_Linux
```

I run the script with:

```
> sh foo.sh
```

When it finishes I try to get the variable but the value is blank.

```
> echo $INSTALL_DIR
```

If I type the command directly the exported var becomes global to the opened terminal window. I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting environment variables is local to the child bash process running your script. To achieve what you want, you need to *source* it like this: `source foo.sh`. It means that it's run by your main bash process. Then, the setting of a variable will remain after the script is finished.

Answer (score 5):

The variable is exported only in **the new shell** you are starting. You probably want to execute your script with `source`.

```
source foo.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer but i know how to overcome it.

```
# source ./foo.sh
# echo $INSTALL_DIR
```

And it's like magic.

I think it's because that script gets executed in it's own "shell". Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Because the process you are running (the shell running your script) can do whatever it wants, but its actions won't affect the parent process (your current shell).

A somewhat weird analogy would be: I can take 5 tequila shots and my environment will become blurry and gravity laws would be affected according to my perception. But to my father, his environment is the same, he doesn't get drunk because of my actions.

If you want that variables created/altered in your script affect your current shell, you should `source` the script as other answers pointed out. Please do note that doing this also may change the resulting working dir in your shell if the script does `cd /whatever/path`, that any other functions setted, but also altered or removed, would get affected in the same way in your shell.

A really weird and not very good analogy would be if I take 5 tekila shots and then my father kills me and drinks my blood.

Am I disturbed or what? ;-)

Comment: your father would get drunk if he has the `source` of your tequila.